# Bowser gets logged in even after logged out on clicking back option

Tags: php, pdo

I  have built a login page using php and pdo and created and logged in properly but after clicking log out button if I click back again it again goes to my page which appear only if logged in I even used session but it is not running properly even

```
    <?php
include('connect.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
{
unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);  
session_destroy();  
header("location:index12.php");
}
}
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
      {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $errflag  = false;
    if($username == '' and $password == '') {
    echo "you must enter username and password";
    $errflag = true;
    }
    if ($errflag == false) {
    SignIn($username,$password);
    }
    }
    function SignIn($username,$password){
    global $connect;
    $search = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username = 
    :username AND password = :password ");
    $search->bindParam(':username',$username);
    $search->bindParam(':password',$password);
    $search->execute();
    $count = $search->rowCount();
    if($count> 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
                header("Location: myfile.php"); 
    }
    else{
        echo "wron email or password";
    }
}
?>
```

the code of inner page is

```
    <?php
echo "welcome to the website ";
echo "congrats you are logged in ";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> 
welcome here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method ="POST" action = "login.php">
<button name="logout" style="float:right;">logout</button>
</form>
<h1><center>google is one of the best search engine</center></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

thankyou I updated the in the above manner but it is not working

Comment: How do you start a session ?

Comment: Please update your answer with the full error message !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bit of code **session_start();** at the beginning of the page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
    {
    unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);  
    session_destroy();  
    header("location:index12.php");
}
}
?>
```

Also if you have not start session in connect.php ,you must need to start session by using **session_start();**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');
```

Comment: the above code was already there in my logout page but it is not working

Comment: it returns the fallwoing error when I keep start_session()  ---                                  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function start_session() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line

Comment: it's `session_start()` not `start_session()` look at my answer @Ram

Comment: sorry @funilrys I didnt look after it but even after appending theese it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you start your session but this a suggestion:

I generally write a new_session() function which looks like the following. I do prefer to set cookie params so we can have some control over it.

```
function new_session()
{
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams['lifetime'], $cookieParams['path'], $cookieParams['domain'], Sessions::SECURED_COOKIES, Sessions::HTTP_ONLY);

    session_name('My_Awesome_App');       
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();

}
```

And another one to destroy everything

```
function destroy_session()
{
    session_unset();

    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);

    session_destroy();
}
```

You can find the documentation about `session_get_cookie_params()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php)
and about `session_set_cookie_params()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

## Back to your example

Using this new function you should call `new_session()` on top of your pages and your logout should look like.

```
new_session();
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) { {
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        destroy_session(); // our new function
        header("location:index12.php");
    }
}
```